# Examples of finite group schemes over a field which are not affine

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, schemes, group-schemes

Let $G$ be finite group scheme over a field $k$. What are some examples of $G$ such that it is not affine?

Comment: Not my meat, so I ask: do you know that there are any such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is immediate from the definition that any finite group scheme (indeed, any finite scheme) over a field is affine.  If a morphism is finite, that means there is an open cover of the base by affine sets whose inverse images are affine and for which the morphism comes from a finite map of rings.  When the base is Spec of a field, this just means the domain scheme itself must be affine (and Spec of a finite-dimensional algebra over the field).  More generally, any finite morphism is affine, so if the codomain is affine then so is the domain.